# "Cannot import name __version__" when installing createsend in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've created a fresh venv running Python 3.3.2. While trying to install Campaign Monitor's `createsend` package via pip, it yields:

```
  Running setup.py egg_info for package createsend
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/vagrant/3.3.2venv/build/createsend/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        from createsend import __version__
      File "./createsend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from createsend import __version__
    ImportError: cannot import name __version__
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/vagrant/3.3.2venv/build/createsend/setup.py", line 5, in <module>

    from createsend import __version__

  File "./createsend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from createsend import __version__

ImportError: cannot import name __version__
```

I believe this package is Python 3 compatible. I'm running the latest version of pip. Can anyone explain why I'm receiving this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [version 4.2.0, released 10 Oct, 2016](https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-python/releases/tag/v.4.2.0), this package is now Python 3 compatible. Old answer, from 2013, follows below.

---

No, this package is **not** Python 3 compatible. It is using relative imports:

```
    from createsend import __version__
  File "./createsend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from createsend import __version__
```

where the second `createsend` is meant to be [`createsend/createsend.py`](https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-python/blob/master/createsend/createsend.py#L16). Instead, Python 3 sees it as an absolute package and the recursive import fails to find the `__version__` name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I didn't realize that relative imports cannot be used in a python 3 package.

Comment: It is not the only problem; just the first.

Comment: The package has been updated, and is now Python 3 compatible.