# How do I install a Python .whl package on a newer platform? (pep425tags)

Tags: python, pip, osx-elcapitan, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am attempting to install a Python version of LinPhone. Following their [Getting Started](https://pythonhosted.org/linphone/getting_started.html) instructions, I tried to directly install by using `sudo pip install linphone --pre`. This 'successfully' downloaded and installed `linphone-3.9.1-py2-none-any.whl`

During `import`, though, I was getting an odd error (identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866930/cannot-import-name-version-when-installing-pip-package-in-python-3), but using Python2.7), I removed `linphone` and went to the [Linphone Python Repository](https://www.linphone.org/snapshots/linphone-python/) and downloaded the latest Mac .whl file and tried to install directly. But I get:

`linphone-3.9.1_361_g26b0a20-cp27-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

After finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform) I realized that this would not build on my `macosx_10_11_intel` machine due to peptags... So I tried the obvious fix and renamed it `linphone-3.9.1_361_g26b0a20-cp27-none-macosx_10_11_intel.whl` which allowed for the install, but caused a completely separate error.

## Question:

Is there a proper way to install a `macosx_10_7_x86_64` whl on a `macosx_10_11_intel` platform outside of renaming the product? Shouldn't there be minimal difference between 10.7 and 10.11?

### Original "Odd" Error:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import linphone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/linphone/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from linphone import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name __version__
```

### Renamed File Error

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import linphone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/linphone/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from linphone import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/linphone/linphone.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/linphone/linphone.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Side comment; I no longer use OS X, but, at least on Linux systems, it is not the best idea to use pip to install system packages. Instead, use a virtualenv if possible, and update pip.  E.g., ```virtualenv ve &&  . ve/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip```. That by itself solved a similar problem for me, but I don't think it will solve your problem. What is your goal in installing from a ```.whl```?

Comment: @mgwilliams I definitely need to read up on virtualenvs, I've seen them mentioned here and there but never used them. As far as my goal in using the .whl; The [official instructions](https://pythonhosted.org/linphone/getting_started.html) state to install using `pip` command and if that doesn't work manually install via `pip` the `nightly-build` from the repo... Which houses .whl files. When that failed I tried to build from source but every dependency I started to build had other dependancies and they were failing left and right... So I'm trying to get Plan A to work lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, turns out the issue was caused when installing linphone package to the default macosx python 2.7.10 installation

I created a virtual environment using a new python 2.7.13 installation (rather than mac osx 2.7.10), installed linphone 3.10.2 from the [wheel file here](https://www.linphone.org/snapshots/linphone-python/macosx/), and it works like a charm!

Note: 3.11.X didn't work for me, kept throwing errors

Running in a virtual env I no longer get the error:

```
ImportError "cannot import name __version__"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: While not able to verify this issue is solved by this, I have found in my time since this, it is a great idea to use a secondary install of python. So I'll mark this as an answer for anyone who may find in future.